# Adobe Audition - auto adjust amplitude

Tags: volume, adobe-audition

I have many audio files, that need to adjust amplitude. Please see `before` image. I need to decrease some parts are over than -6 db to -6 db. But some parts aren't over -6 db, don't need to change.
**Is there a way to do this fast?**

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Answer (score 1):

The best way to approach this is to use a 'dynamics' processor, such as a 'compressor'. This can be configured to take sounds that exhibit energy over a certain threshold and reduce the overall level by a set 'compression ratio'.